# Elastic search conditional field sorting: Cannot cast from [java.util.ArrayList] to [double]

Tags: elasticsearch, spring-data-elasticsearch, elasticsearch-painless

Is it possible to sort elasticsearch documents conditionally? The condition is quite clear, it is visible in my script. When somefield value is present I want to sort by some collection of fields, otherwise, different collection of fields. Fields has different types (strings, numbers). And I would like to sort numbers as numbers (not as strings) so that when sorting ascending this would be correct order (providing that field1 is string and field2 is number).

**Taking only field1 and field2, field3 is empty:**

**ASC:** (A is first part so goes to the top, then numbers are sorted)

```
doc1: AA 2
doc2: H 1
doc3: H 2
```

**DESC:**

```
doc1: H 2
doc2: H 1
doc3: AA 2
```

**When we add other documents, with fields field4-field7 we should have**

**ASC:**

```
H 1 (doc with field1 and field2) 
H 2 (doc with field1 and field2)
1 X 25/2024 (doc with fields4-7)
12 AR 25/2024 (doc with fields4-7)
```

I use spring-data-elasticsearch:

```
 Script script = new Script("myscriptcontent ");
                    ScriptSortBuilder order = SortBuilders.scriptSort(script, ScriptSortBuilder.ScriptSortType.NUMBER)
                            .order(direction.isAscending() ? SortOrder.ASC : SortOrder.DESC);
return nativeSearchQueryBuilder.withSort(order).build();
```

The `ScriptSortBuilder` requires scriptsorttype to be present, however there can be only String and Number, which may not fit here .. Is it possible to build such query with spring-data-elasticsearch ?

The query sort part that I can seen in logs:

```
{
  "_script" : {
    "script" : {
      "source" : "if (doc['somefield.keyword'].size() > 0) { return [doc['field1.keyword'].value, doc['field2.keyword'].value,  doc['field3.keyword'].value]; } else { return [doc['field4.keyword'].value, doc['field5.keyword'].value, doc['field6.keyword'].value, doc['field6.keyword'].value]; } ",
      "lang" : "painless"
    },
    "type" : "number",
    "order" : "desc"
  }
}
```

The effect is this exception:

```
Suppressed: org.elasticsearch.client.ResponseException: method [POST], host [http://localhost:9200], URI [/myindex/_search?typed_keys=true&max_concurrent_shard_requests=5&search_type=query_then_fetch&batched_reduce_size=512], status line [HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request]
{"error":{"root_cause":[{"type":"script_exception","reason":"compile error","script_stack":["... d'].size() > 0) { return [doc['field1.k ...","                             ^---- HERE"],"script":"if (doc['somefield.keyword'].size() > 0) { return [doc['field1.keyword'].value, doc['field2.keyword'].value,  doc['field3.keyword'].value]; } else { return [doc['field4.keyword'].value, doc['field5.keyword'].value, doc['field6.keyword'].value, doc['field7.keyword'].value]; } ","lang":"painless","position":{"offset":56,"start":31,"end":81}}],"type":"search_phase_execution_exception","reason":"all shards failed","phase":"query","grouped":true,"failed_shards":[{"shard":0,"index":"rt","node":"xZy_xw9-R0e-JSfMIeyzBg","reason":{"type":"script_exception","reason":"compile error","script_stack":["... d'].size() > 0) { return [doc['field1.k ...","                             ^---- HERE"],"script":"if (doc['somefield.keyword'].size() > 0) { return [doc['field1.keyword'].value, doc['field2.keyword'].value,  doc['field3.keyword'].value]; } else { return [doc['field4.keyword'].value, doc['field5.keyword'].value, doc['field6.keyword'].value, doc['field7.keyword'].value]; } ","lang":"painless","position":{"offset":56,"start":31,"end":81},"caused_by":{"type":"class_cast_exception","reason":"Cannot cast from [java.util.ArrayList] to [double]."}}}]},"status":400}
..............
3.0.0.war//org.elasticsearch.client.RestHighLevelClient.internalPerformRequest(RestHighLevelClient.java:2171)
        ... 153 more
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using a native query (NativeSearchQuery, that is from the previous version of Spring Data Elasticsearch using the deprecated `RestHighLEvelCLient`) and native query can and must be used when Spring Data Elasticsearch cannot produce the desired queries, scripts etc. So the answer is no. Spring Data Elasticsearch cannot do that.